# jradioboton en java netbeas

Tags: java

como realizo una consulta que al activar el radio botón el filtro me asuma que esa es el tipo de consulta

gracias soy nuevo en java programación[image: realizar consulta]

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta añadiendo el código que lleves hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Sí, mejor sube el código de lo que tienes hecho, porque con la imagen y tu explicación, no se entiende bien si lo que quieres es que al pulsar el JRadioButton pase algo en el cuadro de texto o si cuando pulsas el botón Buscar, tenga en cuenta el cuadro de texto y el estado del JRadioButton

Comment: lo segundo es lo que quiero que haga